# Legal and security issues with wild camping in Ukrainian mountains?

Tags: legal, security, camping, mountains, ukraine

What are the legal and security issues with **wild camping in Ukrainian mountains**?

First of all: is it legal? I've heard, that many groups camp in mountains, including camp fires, and have never had any problems with it. But in some regions, such as **Chornochora**, there is a national park, where camping is allowed only in selected places, and there are not many of them. However, I've also heard of big difference between written law and the practice. So, the camp wardens can try to extort bribes etc. even if you are not breaking the law...

Second, is there the real danger of being attacked or robbed? Can the camp or the rucksacks be left unattented for a few hours?

Third: in case of emergency, is it possible to get help from emergency teams?

Comment: you may find some of these useful if you are after campsites: http://en.camping.info/ukraine/campsites - since you seem to say you've not found many.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> First of all: is it legal?

Well, I have never heard about such problems too.  Regarding Chornogora - yep, it is a kind of national park, there are even some official fees at some entrances, but all camping activities are pretty much allowed.  The only places you may have legal problems at are country borders (like Marmarosy chain) - usually you have to get permission from local border post.  However, there also are real nation parks like [Synevir Lake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synevir) - camping is actually forbidden there.

> Second, is there the real danger of being attacked or robbed? Can the
>   camp or the rucksacks be left unattented for a few hours?

Never heard about robbery in mountains.  However, usually we try not to leave camp unattended (or at least close all entrances, pick money and documents along, etc).

> Third: in case of emergency, is it possible to get help from emergency
>   teams?

Never had such a case, but yes, it is possible, especially at popular\dangerous routes.  Here is contacts of local emergency teams - http://www.verkhovyna.info/ua/verkhovyna/resque/contacts/ (yep, in Ukrainian:().  Anyway, you would better have a native speaker with you on the track - it will be much easier just to ask locals about right way or even get yourself out of some troubles.